How's pole gone in Dirichlet $L$ product
In a part of proof of Dirichlet theorem, you prove $F(s)=\prod_{\chi}L(s,\chi)\geq1$. With that you prove $L(1,\chi)=0$ for all non-principal characters. To prove it you claim $L(1,\chi)=0$ and so $L(1,\bar{\chi})=0$. Then you see $F(s)$ tends to $0$ as $s$ goes $1$ since $L(s,\chi_0)$ has a simple pole at $1$ and you have $2$ zeros, condradiction happens and proof is done. But how is in limit situation this pole is cancelled? It's obvious with intuition but I want to know rigor behind it.

Hint: let $f(z)$ be any meromorphic function in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. If $f(z)$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z=z_0$, then $f(z)=(z-z_0)^k g(z)$ for some analytic function $g(z)$ with $g(z_0)\ne0$; while if $f(z)$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z=z_0$, then $f(z)=(z-z_0)^{-k} g(z)$ for some analytic function $g(z)$ with $g(z_0)\ne0$.

Very sad your pole is gone.
